# How to differentiate $ \intop_{0}^{t}\intop_{0}^{t}e^{\frac{-tx}{y^{2}}}dxdy $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let

$ F\left(t\right)=\intop_{0}^{t}\intop_{0}^{t}e^{\frac{-tx}{y^{2}}}dxdy $

Prove that $ F'\left(t\right)t=2F\left(t\right) $.

Im pretty sure that I should not try to calculate this integral directly. Im not sure how to differentiate it by $ t $ correctly. I'd appreaciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=tX$, $y=tY$ and you get
$$
F(t)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 t^2 e^{-X/Y^2}\,\mathrm{d}X\,\mathrm{d}Y=t^2\cdot\text{constant}
$$
so the result follows (as long as that constant is finite, which it is).